# What is the best way to create dynamic input fields and map db column with filter using reactJS?

Tags: reactjs, nestjs

I want to create a component in which user can build filters for charts and map db column with that filter. For example i have a chart in which x and y axis are dynamic and admin can map any column with these axis and admin can build dynamic filters which can text, date or number type and when end user see charts they will see filter as well with options and default value etc.

I am using reactJS and nestJS respectievely. Is there any good package for that purpose or any body can guide road map to create above functionality.